# Scipy cannot import median_abs_deviation

Tags: python, module, scipy, python-import

I'm using a program called galpro which uses may packages, including scipy. When I use the command

`import galpro as gp`

I am then given the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6eb7571a326c> in <module>
----> 1 import galpro as gp

~/galpro/galpro/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .model import Model

~/galpro/galpro/model.py in <module>
      8 import joblib
      9 import h5py
---> 10 from .validation import Validation
     11 from .plot import Plot
     12 from .utils import convert_1d_arrays, create_directories

~/galpro/galpro/validation.py in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import h5py
----> 4 from .plot import Plot
      5 from .utils import load_posteriors, create_templates
      6 from .conf import set_plot_params

~/galpro/galpro/plot.py in <module>
      4 import seaborn as sns
      5 import statsmodels.api as sm
----> 6 from .utils import *
      7 from .conf import set_plot_params
      8 

~/galpro/galpro/utils.py in <module>
      3 import h5py
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 from scipy.stats import entropy, kstest, median_abs_deviation, cramervonmises
      6 
      7 

ImportError: cannot import name 'median_abs_deviation' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried reinstalling scipy and this didn't help. According to documentation, the median_abs_deviation module should work with scipy 1.3.0 onwards, and I'm using 1.5.4. I have also tried reinstalling different versions of scipy and this has not helped either.

Comment: it could depend on the dependency `statsmodels` that can be installed with:

    `pip install statsmodels`

Comment: @XxJames07- @ That doesn't seem to be the problem, I tried reinstalling statsmodels there and it still isn't working.

Comment: Using the same style of running python as you do when run `import galpro as gp`, run the command `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  What does it print?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser It is version 1.3.0, which should theoretically run mean_abs_deviation

Comment: Version 1.3.0 does not have `median_abs_deviation`. The function was added in version 1.5.0, as noted in its [docstring](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.median_abs_deviation.html).